# Show that $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A,B$ be subset of a topological space, show that $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}$. (The bar denotes closure)

I have totally no clue, please give me some idea.

Comment: By the way, equality doesn't hold (consider two disjoint open intervals which meet at the boundary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A\cap B\subset A$ and $A\cap B\subset B$ so the same is true for closures.